# Prevent re-buffering on changing max bit rate in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using `setMaxBitrate` provided by `DefaultTrackSelector` to set max bit rate when user changes video quality.

```
val parameters = defaultTrackSelector.buildUponParameters()
            .setMaxVideoBitrate(bitrate)
            .build()

defaultTrackSelector.parameters = parameters
```

But as soon as this function is called, the current buffer is discarded & re-buffering is shown right away. Is there any way to keep playing using old buffer & just load the new buffer using the new bitrate settings like YouTube does?

This issue has been discussed here:
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3522
https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2250

But there doesn't seem to be any solution yet. Any help regarding this issue would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that the way around this issue would be to start fetching video in a different resolution in parallel and then replace the old one with it when it reaches the last fetched media chunk for a smooth transition. Otherwise, the ExoPlayer will discard the buffer the moment you change the bit rate.

Comment: @IvanV Seems like a lot of hack. We need to create a new instance of the ExoPlayer parallelly to start fetching video in different resolution & running two instances might affect memory also. I wonder why the ExoPlayer discards the current buffer when we change max bit rate, is there any rational behind it. Atleast, it should provide an option to keep current buffer.

Comment: Will be watching this thread, but im sure there's a custom track selector that can do this job

Answer (score 2):

Easily you can do it.You have to use `ExoPlayer` already and `ExoPlayer` is provide a `seekTo()` method.

On this method,You should pass only player current position at which point you stopped before.

**Step:-1** 
You have to change your Quality like 144p to 720p. on this Changing time you have to store your current `ExoPlayer` current position used this method:-

```
Private int currentPosition=player.getCurrentPosition();
```

**Step -2** 
After you have to build your exoplayer media source:-

```
// Measures bandwidth during playback. Can be null if not required.
        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        // Produces DataSource instances through which media data is loaded.
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, Util.getUserAgent(this, getString(R.string.app_name)), bandwidthMeter);
        // This is the MediaSource representing the media to be played.
        MediaSource videoSource = new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource("Pass Your Video Url");
        // Prepare the player with the source.
        player.prepare(videoSource);
```

**Step 3:-** 
check this condition

```
if (this.currentPosition > 0) {
        player.seekTo(this.currentPosition);
        this.currentPosition = 0;
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    } else {
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }
```

and it's work good you have to watch your video in where are you left.

**Step 4:-** 
If your quality his not good that time used is method.

```
public int getWifiLevel()
{
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int linkSpeed = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(linkSpeed, 5);
    return level;
}
```

Based on wifi level or link speed you can decide if it has the low connection or high connection internet.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but this doesn't answer my question. The issue is not with the player seek position, exoplayer itself is handling this i.e it resumes the video from the current position itself, we don't have to explicitly seek. The issue is with buffer, imagine you are playing in 720p, the exoplayer would have downloaded next few segments of video in 720p resolution.  But as soon as max bit rate is changed, these segments are discarded & new segments are fetched again.

Comment: @AbhishekV I am facing the same problem. Have you found the solution?